# Python to convert JavascriptSerializer to datetime?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime

My JSON file has date and time in JavascriptSerializer format as in below,

```
{"StartDate": "/Date(1519171200000)/",
"EndDate": "/Date(1519257600000)/",}
```

How to convert it to datetime like this?

```
"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z" - JavaScript built-in JSON object
"2012-04-21T18:25:43-05:00" - ISO 8601
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a solution for this, though may not be an efficient one but still helped me.

```
>s_time = re.sub("\D", '', "/Date(1519171200000)/")
>d_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(s_time) / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

>print (d_time)

>2018-02-21 13:58:02
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime but must devide by 1000 to get the seconds
time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1519171200000/1000)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).